# Stress Distribution Around a Circular Hole (Polar Plot)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Using the Kirsch equations for an infinite plate with a circular hole under tension, plot the radial and tangential stress distribution as a function of the angle (θ) around the hole. The Kirsch equations are given by: For an infinite plate with a hole of radius a subjected to a remote stress (tangential), the stresses at a point in the material at a distance r from the center of the hole and at an angle theta from the load axis are given by: radial stress(θ)= applied uniaxial tensile stress[1+ (a<sup>2</sup>/r<sup>2</sup>)(1.5cos(2θ)+cos(4θ)+(3a<sup>4</sup>/2r<sup>4</sup>)cos(4θ)] and tangential(θ)=applied uniaxial tensile stress[1+ (a<sup>2</sup>/r<sup>2</sup>)(0.5cos(2θ)-cos(4θ)+(3a<sup>4</sup>/2r<sup>4</sup>)cos(4θ)].r is the radial distance from the center of the hole (you can assume r=a).

When I ran my code I got a graph that does not resemble what the actual polar plot is supposed to look like.
Is there something I'm missing in this code? Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!
[Graph that my code produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXakH.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

applied_stress = 178.53  # Applied uniaxial tensile stress
hole_radius = 0.042   # Radius of the circular hole


theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)


r = hole_radius  # Assume r = a
radial_stress = applied_stress * (1 + (hole_radius**2 / r**2) * (1.5 * np.cos(2 * theta) + np.cos(4 * theta) + (3 * hole_radius**4 / (2 * r**4)) * np.cos(4 * theta)))
tangential_stress = applied_stress * (1 + (hole_radius**2 / r**2) * (0.5 * np.cos(2 * theta) - np.cos(4 * theta) + (3 * hole_radius**4 / (2 * r**4)) * np.cos(4 * theta)))


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

ax.plot(theta, radial_stress, label='Radial Stress')
ax.plot(theta, tangential_stress, label='Tangential Stress')


ax.set_rlabel_position(135)
plt.title('Radial and Tangential Stress Distribution')
plt.legend()


plt.show()
```

Comment: What should it look like?

Comment: Where did you get your equations from? I see none with a 4.theta in.

Comment: Honestly, it was the equation that my professor provided, when i searched it up I couldn't find any with 4theta either.

Comment: The graph is supposed to be two circles, one for the radial stress and one for the tangential stress.